# Problem with Go back link after submission of Webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I programmatically created  a custom contactform using webform and it render into another page.Webform submission and redirection working in good.

[image]

***But i can't come back to my contact page by clicking Go back link in the redirected page.***

Comment: Isn't it a static link? There should be no reason for it to now work in that case, unless the `href` of the link is pointing to some other location.

Comment: How are you pointing to the go back link? Is it a static url? Or is it being set via javascript?

Comment: It's a static link